# Which Eclipse plugin contains class MarkerSupportView

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am trying to create a Problems view alternative by extending the MarkerSupportView, but I cannot find the plugin that defines it. I know MarkerSupportView only exists @since 3.4, but I use 3.6. I have searched the Eclipse plugins directory for a jar likely to contain the class, but still could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MarkerSupportView` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin.

To find classes in the Eclipse plugins go to `Preferences > Plug-in Development` and check the `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search`. Once this is set the `Navigate > Open Type...` dialog will search all the plugins in your target platform for classes.

If you have the Eclipse source installed then `Open Type` will show you the class source.